# For every $t$, with probability one, $B_t \not = 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

My professor gives two similar arguments and he claims that they are different without giving any extra explanations. Could you help to check if my understandings are correct?

Let's assume $B_t : (\Omega, \Sigma, P) \to (\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$.

> With probability one, for every $t$, $B_t \not = 1$.

My understanding: $P(A) = 1$, where $A = \{B_t \not = 1: t \ge 0\} \subset (\Omega, \Sigma, P)$.

> For every $t$, with probability one, $B_t \not = 1$.

My understanding: $P(A_t) =1$, for every $t$, where $A_t = \{B_t \not = 1\} \subset (\Omega, \Sigma, P)$

Do I define these events inside the probability symbol $P$ correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yeah, those are two distinct events, and so far as I understand you have defined them correctly.**

Note that $A=\cap_{t\geq 0} A_t$ is way more restrictive than $A_{t_0}$ for any fixed $t_0$.

In general, a *countable* intersection of events with probability one will have probability one, but $A$ is an intersection of *uncountable* events with full probability, which is a crucial difference.

Comment: After reading your answer to my another question, would it be more explicit to define $A = \{ \omega \in \Omega : B_t(\omega) \not = 1 \text{ for } t \ge 0 \}$? And, $A_t = \{ \omega \in \Omega :  B_t \not = 1 \}$?

Comment: Yes! The $\omega\in \Omega $ is usually ommitted to save space, but that would be the way to do so. For $A_t$ I would also write $B_t(\omega)$ if I wanted to be fully specific: $$A_t=\{\omega  \in \Omega : B_t(\omega)\neq 1\}.$$